# Zencart - How can I set a theme/template programmatically?

Tags: themes, smartphone, zen-cart

I am trying to select a particular template on the basis of device browser. I am using Anthony Hand's library from http://www.mobileesp.com for detecting the device and then I want to set template programmatically. The library works like that

```
require_once 'mdetect.php';

//Instantiate the object
$uagent_obj = new uagent_info();

//Detect iPhone
if ($uagent_obj->DetectTierIphone() == $uagent_obj->true) {
    echo '<!-- Setting Theme for Smart devices -->';
}

//Detect All Other Mobile Devices
else if ($uagent_obj->DetectTierOtherPhones() == $uagent_obj->true) {
    echo '<!-- Setting Theme for Smart devices -->';
}
```

Please guide how can I do this in ZenCart?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution don't know whether it is up to standard or not. The reason could be I couldn't found any hook for setting the template. What I did is I inserted the script in the `init_templates.php` file located at `~/includes/init_includes/init_templates.php` just after the definition of `$template_dir`

```
require_once 'mdetect.php'; //set the path of file according to your folder structure. The link to mdetec script is given in the question detail.

//Instantiate the object
$uagent_obj = new uagent_info();

//Detect iPhone
if ($uagent_obj->DetectTierIphone() == $uagent_obj->true) {
   $template_dir = 'iphonetemplate';
}

//Detect All Other Mobile Devices
else if ($uagent_obj->DetectTierOtherPhones() == $uagent_obj->true) {
   $template_dir = 'mobiletemplate';
}
```

to run this flawlessly, the template must be placed in your `templates` directory. Mostly these are located at `~/includes/templates/<template_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Template is defined in MySQL table `template_select` and is read on breakpoint 110 (according to includes/auto_loaders/config.core.php). You should define following constants before this breakpoint to override it:

- DIR_WS_TEMPLATE
- DIR_WS_TEMPLATE_IMAGES
- DIR_WS_TEMPLATE_ICONS
- and set variable $template_dir

For more information check file 'includes/init_includes/init_templates.php'.